# How can I find the highest (latest) and lowest (earliest) dates in a column?

Tags: datetime, r, time

I’m attempting to transform two columns in my dataframe to the ‘good’ date & time class, and until now didn’t have much success with it. I’ve tried various classes (`timeDate`, `Date`, `timeSeries`, `POSIXct`, `POSIXlt`) but without success. Perhaps I’m just overlooking the obvious and because I’ve tried so many approaches I just don’t know what’s what anymore. I hope some of you can shed some light on where I go wrong.

**Goal**: 
I want to calculate the difference between two dates using the earliest and latest date. I got this working with `head()` and `tail()`, but because those values aren’t necessary the earliest and latest date in my data, I need another way. (I can’t get the sorting of data to work, because it sorts the data only on the day of the date.)

**Second goal**: I want to convert the dates from daily format (i.e. 8-12-2010) to weekly, monthly, and yearly levels (i.e. '49-2010', 'december-10', and just '2010'). This can be done with the format settings (like `%d-%m-%y`). Can this be done with converting the data.frame to an time class, and than transforming the timeclass in the right format `(8-12-2010 -> format("%B-%y") -> 'december-10'`), and then transforming that time class into an factor with levels for each month?

For both goals I need to convert the dateframe in some way to an time class, and this is where I ran into some difficulties.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
> tradesList[c(1,10,11,20),14:15] -> tmpTimes4
> tmpTimes4
   EntryTime ExitTime
1   01-03-07 10-04-07
10  29-10-07 02-11-07
11  13-04-07 14-05-07
20  18-12-07 20-02-08
```

Here’s an summary of what I’ve tried:

```
> class(tmpTimes4)
[1] "data.frame"
> as.Date(head(tmpTimes4$EntryTimes, n=1), format="%d-%m-%y")
Error in as.Date.default(head(tmpTimes4$EntryTimes, n = 1), format = "%d-%m-%y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'head(tmpTimes4$EntryTimes, n = 1)' to class "Date"
> as.timeDate(tmpTimes4, format="%d-%m-%y")
Error in as.timeDate(tmpTimes4, format = "%d-%m-%y") : 
  unused argument(s) (format = "%d-%m-%y")
> timeSeries(tmpTimes4, format="%d-%m-%y")
Error in midnightStandard2(charvec, format) : 
  'charvec' has non-NA entries of different number of characters
> tmpEntryTimes4 <- timeSeries(tmpTimes4$EntryTime, format="%d-%m-%y")
> tmpExitTimes4 <- timeSeries(tmpTimes4$ExitTime, format="%d-%m-%y")
> tmpTimes5 <- cbind(tmpEntryTimes4,tmpExitTimes4)
> colnames(tmpTimes5) <- c("Entry","Exit")
> tmpTimes5
     Entry    Exit    
[1,] 01-03-07 10-04-07
[2,] 29-10-07 02-11-07
[3,] 13-04-07 14-05-07
[4,] 18-12-07 20-02-08
> class(tmpTimes5)
[1] "timeSeries"
attr(,"package")
[1] "timeSeries"
> as.timeDate(tmpTimes5, format="%d-%m-%y")
Error in as.timeDate(tmpTimes5, format = "%d-%m-%y") : 
  unused argument(s) (format = "%d-%m-%y")
> as.Date(tmpTimes5, format="%d-%m-%y")
Error in as.Date.default(tmpTimes5, format = "%d-%m-%y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'tmpTimes5' to class "Date"
> format.POSIXlt(tmpTimes5, format="%d-%m-%y", usetz=FALSE)
Error in format.POSIXlt(tmpTimes5, format = "%d-%m-%y", usetz = FALSE) : 
  wrong class
> as.POSIXlt(tmpTimes5, format="%d-%m-%y", usetz=FALSE)
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(tmpTimes5, format = "%d-%m-%y", usetz = FALSE) : 
  do not know how to convert 'tmpTimes5' to class "POSIXlt"
> as.POSIXct(tmpTimes5, format="%d-%m-%y", usetz=FALSE)
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz, ...) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class "POSIXlt"
```

The TimeDate packages has an function for ‘range’, however, converting to the Date class works for an individual instance, but for some reason not for an data frame:

```
> as.Date(tmpTimes4[1,1], format="%d-%m-%y")
[1] "2007-03-01"
> as.Date(tmpTimes4, format="%d-%m-%y")
Error in as.Date.default(tmpTimes4, format = "%d-%m-%y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'tmpTimes4' to class "Date"
```

At this point I almost believe it’s impossible to do, so any thoughts would be highly appreciated!

Regards,

Comment: You could use `dput(tmpTimes4)` to provide exact dataset use in your code.

Comment: @Marek: Thanks for responding! I didn't know about dput, so thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Start with some dummy data:

```
start <- as.Date("2010/01/01")
end <- as.Date("2010/12/31")
set.seed(1)
datewant <- seq(start, end, by = "days")[sample(15)]
tmpTimes <- data.frame(EntryTime = datewant, 
                       ExitTime = datewant + sample(100, 15))
## reorder on EntryTime so in random order
tmpTimes <- tmpTimes[sample(NROW(tmpTimes)), ]
head(tmpTimes)
```

so we have something like this:

```
> head(tmpTimes)
    EntryTime   ExitTime
8  2010-01-14 2010-03-16
9  2010-01-05 2010-01-17
7  2010-01-10 2010-01-30
3  2010-01-08 2010-04-16
10 2010-01-01 2010-01-26
13 2010-01-12 2010-02-15
```

Using the above, look at **Goal 1**, compute difference between earliest and latest date. You can treat dates as if they were numbers (that is how they are stored internally anyway), so functions like `min()` and `max()` will work. You can use the `difftime()` function:

```
> with(tmpTimes, difftime(max(EntryTime), min(EntryTime)))
Time difference of 14 days
```

or use standard subtraction

```
> with(tmpTimes, max(EntryTime) - min(EntryTime))
Time difference of 14 days
```

to get the difference in days. `head()` and `tail()` will only work if you sort the dates as these take the first and the last value in a vector, not the highest and lowest actual value.

**Goal 2:** You seem to be trying to convert a data frame to a Date. You can't do this. What you can do is reformat the data in the *components* of the data frame. Here I add columns to `tmpTimes` by reformatting the `EntryTime` column into several different summaries of the date.

```
tmpTimes2 <- within(tmpTimes, weekOfYear <- format(EntryTime, format = "%W-%Y"))
tmpTimes2 <- within(tmpTimes2, monthYear <- format(EntryTime, format = "%B-%Y"))
tmpTimes2 <- within(tmpTimes2, Year <- format(EntryTime, format = "%Y"))
```

Giving:

```
> head(tmpTimes2)
    EntryTime   ExitTime weekOfYear    monthYear Year
8  2010-01-14 2010-03-16    02-2010 January-2010 2010
9  2010-01-05 2010-01-17    01-2010 January-2010 2010
7  2010-01-10 2010-01-30    01-2010 January-2010 2010
3  2010-01-08 2010-04-16    01-2010 January-2010 2010
10 2010-01-01 2010-01-26    00-2010 January-2010 2010
13 2010-01-12 2010-02-15    02-2010 January-2010 2010
```

If you are American or want to use the US convention for the start of the week (`%W` starts the week on a Monday, in US convention is to start on a Sunday), change the `%W` to `%U`. `?strftime` has more details of what `%W` and `%U` represent.

---

**A final point on data format:** In the above I have worked with dates in standard R format. You have your data stored in a data frame in a non-standard markup, presumably as characters or factors. So you have something like:

```
tmpTimes3 <- within(tmpTimes, 
                    EntryTime <- format(EntryTime, format = "%d-%m-%y"))
tmpTimes3 <- within(tmpTimes3, 
                    ExitTime <- format(ExitTime, format = "%d-%m-%y"))

> head(tmpTimes3)
   EntryTime ExitTime
8   14-01-10 16-03-10
9   05-01-10 17-01-10
7   10-01-10 30-01-10
3   08-01-10 16-04-10
10  01-01-10 26-01-10
13  12-01-10 15-02-10
```

You need to convert those characters or factors to something R understands as a date. My preference would be the `"Date"` class. Before you try the above answers with your data, convert your data to the correct format:

```
tmpTimes3 <- 
    within(tmpTimes3, {
           EntryTime <- as.Date(as.character(EntryTime), format = "%d-%m-%y")
           ExitTime <- as.Date(as.character(ExitTime), format = "%d-%m-%y")
           })
```

so that your data looks like this:

```
> head(tmpTimes3)
    EntryTime   ExitTime
8  2010-01-14 2010-03-16
9  2010-01-05 2010-01-17
7  2010-01-10 2010-01-30
3  2010-01-08 2010-04-16
10 2010-01-01 2010-01-26
13 2010-01-12 2010-02-15
> str(tmpTimes3)
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ EntryTime:Class 'Date'  num [1:15] 14623 14614 14619 14617 14610 ...
 $ ExitTime :Class 'Date'  num [1:15] 14684 14626 14639 14715 14635 ...
```

Comment: Wow Gavin, thanks alot! You really helped me out, not just with the code example, but also with the excellent (and clear) text. Thanks again, I get it now completely, and just succeeded with calculating the number of days, transforming the dates, and displaying the resuls per time period. Yes! :)

Comment: @Jura25: glad you found it useful.

Comment: Indeed, min and max work for date, but if you have any NA in your date column, pleas use the na.rm=TRUE e.g. stardate<-min(DateofTest,na.rm=TRUE). Save yourself the puzzled scratch on the head.

Comment: @PanchoMulongeni The only reason for `NA` in a *Date* variable is an invalid date (i.e. incorrectly formatted, or a date that didn't exist). I don't think ignoring that is a good thing and you should investigate why the `NA`s are there. If they are there because you didn't record the date, get rid of them too; if you don't know the date the data is useless.

Comment: @GavinSimpson. great answer. Small typo in "> with(tmpTimes, difftime(max(EntryTime), main(EntryTime)))
Time difference of 14 days" think should be min() not main()?

Answer (score 14):

Short answer:

- Convert to date if not already done.
- Then use min and max on the list
  of dates.

  ```
  date_list = structure(c(15401, 15405, 15405), class = "Date")
  date_list
  #[1] "2012-03-02" "2012-03-06" "2012-03-06"

  min(date_list)
  #[1] "2012-03-02"
  max(date_list)
  #[1] "2012-03-06"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(dates = structure(c(15401, 15405, 15505, 16506), class = "Date"))
df
#>        dates
#> 1 2012-03-02
#> 2 2012-03-06
#> 3 2012-06-14
#> 4 2015-03-12

# earliest and oldest dates in this order 
# diff is the difference between earliest and oldest dates
df %>%
  arrange(desc(df)) %>%
  slice(c(1, nrow(.))) %>%
  mutate(diff = lag(dates) - dates)
#>        dates      diff
#> 1 2015-03-12   NA days
#> 2 2012-03-02 1105 days
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

More easy. Use `summary()` on date column directly giving Min and Max and more. Example: `summary(df$date)`

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer